# 2 plots on same matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have 2 sets of coordinates that I want to plot on the same matrix.

This is my code:

```
self.ax.imshow(arr,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
self.ax.imshow(arr.T, cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation = 'none')
```

However this does not work. It only seems to plot the one that is called last.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: imshow of a matrix completely fills the 2D space of the graph.  What would you like to happen when you call it twice?  Maybe you just want two images side by side?  If you post an image of each separate and the combination you would like, I'm sure you'll get an answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but if you just want the sum of both matrices plotted, then try,

```
self.ax.imshow(arr+are.T,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
```

though note it only works if arr and are.T have equal shape.